# Using jQuery in Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jsdom

Hi I am new here and hope that I can make myself clear. I've been trying to call(?) jQuery in node.js, but everything I do results a failure. I've been trying to solve this for hours and still stuck hopefully there is someone who can help me with this !

I am trying to fetch some info from twitch using their api. In this case if a streamer is online or offline. When I open the page localy ( without node.js) the jQuery code works fine. However when I try to use node.js it gives errors on this: $.

This is after some research and random trying.. (still new to node.js and jQuery):

`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNC0z.jpg

`

Edit: The reason why I am trying to use node.js is to update my website without refreshing. So If someone goes online/offline, he/she should not be forced to refresh.

Comment: What version of JSDOM do you have installed?

Comment: Please, embed the image with you answer. External links are bad, because once the external resource is gone, the question becomes less valuable.

Comment: Since I am new here, there is a restriction on images. I will update the question later on when I get 10 reputation.

jsdom version :
  "_from": "jsdom@latest",
  "_id": "jsdom@11.0.0",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_location": "/jsdom",
  "_nodeVersion": "7.5.0",

Comment: @Smil3 You don't need an *image* to convey the information. Copy and paste the relevant text into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"When the only tool you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail."

In this case, you're trying to use the wrong tool for the job. jQuery is built and optimized specifically for use in a browser environment. While you could force it to work by having a shadow DOM... don't.

If you wanted to use jQuery's selectors and DOM manipulation features, `cheerio` basically implements that API, but specifically for Node.js/server-side.

However, you sound like you want to use it's `ajax()` method (or one of it's helpers like `post()` or `get()`.

Instead, you should use something built for Node. `node-fetch` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) is an excellent and easy to use option that was designed specifically for Node.js.

Here is a simple example from its documentation:

```
fetch('https://github.com/')
.then(function(res) {
    return res.text();
}).then(function(body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

You first call `fetch()` with the URL you want. It'll return a `Promise` with a `Response` object. From that, you can extract the `text()` or anything else, and from there you can parse it.

If you need to pass options, call a different method (like POST), etc., you'll just give it an options object as the second parameter to the first call (check out their documentation).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Feels like I'm halfway there. I tried with node-fetch, however the problem I'm having right now is about sending the "client-id". Since I'm not sending the client-id, it's giving me HTTP 400 error.

https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/guides/using-the-twitch-api  : "Requests can include both a client ID and an OAuth token. Requests without either one fail with an HTTP 400 error."

Comment: See, **this** is how to use fetch

Comment: @Smil3 Looks like there are two ways to send it. The easiest is just to add it to your URL: `twitch.url?client_id=your_id_here`. The other would be to send it as a header (that's what the `-H` is for cURL), which you can do by passing an object as the second parameter to `fetch()` with headers: `fetch(url, { headers: { 'Client-ID': 'your_id_here' } })`. If you need help beyond that, try to work it out on your own, and then post a new question with your updated work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `npm` module you can use that is based off `jsdom`.
It will give you a window object.
Example:

```
var express = require('express');
var Window = require('window');
global.window = new Window();
global.document = window.document;
var $ = require('jquery');
var app = express();
function game() {
   $("body").append(`<h1>Hello world!</h1>`);
}
game();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML)
});
```